# how to refine an if statement that effects multiple variables?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list with a drop down menu and each selection effects multiple variables.
is there any way to refine it down? here is a snippet:

```
if (selectedLeft == 'item 1')
  row1Vis = false;
if (selectedLeft == 'item 1')
  leftCounter = false;
if (selectedLeft == 'item 1')
  leftNA = true;
```

is it possible to have it something like,
if (selectedLeft == 'item 1')
row1Vis = false, leftCounter = false, leftNA = true;

so i don't have to write out if (selectedLeft == 'item 1') 3 times.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `if` body for your variable and also use `&&`, `||` if you want to use two or more conditions. `&&` means `AND`, `||` means `OR`:

```
if(selectedLeft == 'item 1' && selectRight == 'item 2') {
  row1Vis = false;
  leftCounter = false; 
  leftNA = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use body `(){...}`

```dart
if (selectedLeft == 'item 1') {
  row1Vis = false;
  leftCounter = false;
  leftNA = true;
}
```

More about [if-and-else](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#if-and-else) , [switch-and-case](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case) on  [language-tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: thanks so much for the help. is it also possible to do an AND statement? as in if(selectedLeft == 'item 1' AND selectRight == 'item 2') {row1Vis = false;
  leftCounter = false;
  leftNA = true;
}

Comment: Yes you can, you can explore those links, `language-tour` will provide the information you need for start-up